# Android Studio Preview Differs from Actual Device

Tags: android, emulation, virtual, device, android-virtual-device

I am having a bit of difficulty with regards to getting the "Preview" of an xml layout to accurately reflect what will show on my galaxy S5. I use genymotion to run the applications (Which is accurate) but I would like to have an AVD of the an S5 so I can see the changes made in real time while I code. I have created a hardware profile using the Galaxy S5 specs (Screen size 1080x1920). The real-time preview still appears different to the Genymotion and actual S5 screen after run-time. Can anyone guess why?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The title to this question is misleading. It appears that you can successfully create AVDs, right? Can you edit the title to more accurately reflect your actual question.

Comment: I would like to set up "Preview" (during xml)  to replicate exactly what my device will display.

Comment: You've switched to a 1080x1920 preview size, right? (Nexus 5)

Comment: Yes I guess they have the same sizes. Perhaps it's the dpi?